# model class is not a subtype of type int

Tags: flutter, dart

when user likes the other user post, I get this error:-

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type 'ModelClassData' is not a subtype of type 'int'


DocumentSnapshot docUser = await _reference.doc(widget.users[index].uid)?.get();  //// error brings me to [index]
    print('userUid: ${widget.users[index].uid}');
    _reference.doc(widget.users[index].uid).update(
        {
          "likeRec": docUser.data()['likeRec']+1,
        });
```

Comment: is widget.users a list? I think it is not a list should be an object

Comment: yes it is a list and  I am getting all the other data of user.

Comment: if I put object in place of list then I get this error:- The type 'Object' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given.

Comment: Could you share ModelClassData part?

Comment: I want to but that is too long. I can share with u if want to check anything specific that I can tell u.